# Intento de login en una app django (sin DRF) desde postman

Tags: django, postman

Tengo una app django publicada en DigitalOcean. Estoy intentando probar el login desde postman y me retorna 403 "La verificación CSRF ha fallado. Solicitud abortada."

A nivel de Postman lo estoy configurando de la siguiente manera pero no logro pasar el login. Tampoco tengo claro si desde aca podría hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecido con quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la longitud de X-Csrftoken? No olvides poner el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Para poder obtener un token de la forma en que lo tengo armado primero tengo que hacer un GET (¿es correcto hacerlo asi?) y ahi me devuelve un token de 32 caracteres. El error dice que la longitud es incorrecta